# Jolt spec to collapse any field with a `name` key nested

Tags: json, jolt

The input is

```json
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "foo": "fooooooo",
    "bar": "bbbbbbarr",
    "recordtype": {
      "name": "type123",
      "some_field": "don't care"
    },
    "parent": {
      "name": "parent123",
      "some_field": "don't care"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 456,
    "foo": "ooooooff",
    "bar": "rrrrraaabbbb",
    "recordtype": {
      "name": "type456",
      "some_field": "don't care"
    },
    "parent": {
      "name": "parent789",
      "some_field": "don't care"
    }
  }
]
```

The desired output is

```json
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "foo": "fooooooo",
    "bar": "bbbbbbarr",
    "recordtype": {
      "name": "type123",
      "some_field": "don't care"
    },
    "parent": {
      "name": "parent123",
      "some_field": "don't care"
    },
    "recordtype_name": "type123",
    "parent_name": "parent123"
  },
  {
    "id": 456,
    "foo": "ooooooff",
    "bar": "rrrrraaabbbb",
    "recordtype": {
      "name": "type456",
      "some_field": "don't care"
    },
    "parent": {
      "name": "parent789",
      "some_field": "don't care"
    },
    "recordtype_name": "type456",
    "parent_name": "parent789"
  }
]
```

Where any object with a nested `name` key gets concatenated with its parent key (e.g. parent and recordtype), becoming `parent_name` and `recordtype_name` respectively.  I also need all original keys and values in the result object.

What I’ve tried.  This works but all original keys are gone.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "name": "[&2].&1_&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better to use a **modify** transformation spec as being more straightforward :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "recordtype_name": "@(1,recordtype.name)",
        "parent_name": "@(1,parent.name)"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Yet, you can prefer using **shift** transformation spec like this as an alternative :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "[&2].&",
          "name": "[&2].&1_&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** is

[image]

If the order of the appearance matters for the second case(the one uses **shift**), then the following spec might be preferred :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "[&1]",
        "recordtype|parent": {
          "name": "[&2].&1_&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```